# ASP.NET MVC @Html.Raw() not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-encode

I have this line of code here in my view

I have this string `@Model.inventory.overview` and it has `&mdash;` in it.

When I try to use it so it will display the special html character it shows up as the text `&mdash;`

```
@Html.Raw(Model.inventory.overview)
```

and

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(Model.inventory.overview)
```

This is what `@Model.inventory.overview` is

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit`&mdash;`amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
>   Mauris eget feugiat nibh. Fusce rhoncus ex et nunc fringilla, ut
>   fermentum tortor volutpat. Praesent mollis efficitur magna auctor
>   sollicitudin. Morbi pulvinar, justo ut efficitur rutrum, dui metus
>   varius magna, vitae molestie leo elit vel turpis. Nullam quis ipsum
>   nec erat maximus dictum sit amet sed ligula. Vestibulum tincidunt
>   dolor non`&mdash;`justo accumsan, eu euismod neque rutrum. Donec in
>   lacinia est.

I have also tried the following:

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@model.ContentBody));
```

Still not working.

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML.

Comment: There ya go....

Comment: But if you remove the `&mdash;` code comments this works? What makes you think this isn't working? Do you want it to display the text `&mdash;` or the mdash icon?

Comment: What do you see when you view the page source? I wonder of it is being escaped.

Comment: @Liam yes I want to display the mdash icon

Comment: So it works here? There is no reason for it not to work on your web site? What you have put into this question cannont be the actual HTML on your page?

Comment: @Liam, its not working, its not displaying the icon

Comment: so why does it work here? If I remove the `code` comments form what you put in this question is displays the icon. So if it doesn't work you have not given us the information to solve your problem?!

Comment: @Liam, that is all the info I have, I have that paragraph in a database, I put into my Model and displayed it like so `@Html.Raw(Model.inventory.overview)` No icon, just &mdash;

Comment: `@Html.Raw(Model.inventory.overview)` should work. If it's not then your doing something unusual that you've not shared. There's nothing more anyone can add to this question unless you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Comment: Try `@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.inventory.overview))` and let us know the result.

Comment: I would suspect that the value stored in your database is `&amp;mdash;`

Comment: @Tiramonium that workes! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.inventory.overview))` was the solution after all.

I looked at [W3C Html ASCII characters list](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp) and had a suspicion `&mdash;` wasn't "exactly" a ASCII character, so I found [this site](https://pc.net/helpcenter/answers/meaning_of_mdash) soon after. Glad I was helpful.